# How to create light-4j fatjar for Docker

Tags: light-4j

I'm trying to run your petstore-example and made it up to the building and running the server via mvn install exec:exec ... but now I'm trying to do the docker part: Where I wonder since you only ADD the petstore.jar to the docker-image, but not all the other dependency jar's (like the server). Therefore the Main-Class com.networknt.server.Server can not be found in the docker-container.

Answer (score 0):

There is build.sh in the generated project that is used to build a docker image and publish it to the docker hub. You need to change the docker organization in the file thought. To build a fat jar in the command line, you can use `mvn install -Prelease`

If you are generating the project with the light-codegen, you can update the config.json to specify the docker hub organization instead of the default networknt.

Please be aware that some of the examples generated in the past might have a build.sh with command line `mvn clean install` instead of `mvn clean install -Prelease` Please let us know and we can regenerate them.